# Synchronize setting a variable which is outside javascript function

Tags: javascript

below this text there is code what I tryed.
I want to achive this: outside function geocoder.geocode there is variable called **var address**. geocoder.geocode ... gets addres from latlng, and I want to set the address by this `row address = results[1].formatted_address;`
but the varriable address is probably not visible outside. 
When I call: `alert('Inside: '+ address)` address is **correctly set**,
but whe I call same outside the function `alert ('Outside address: '+address)` the address is back **empty string**, so **setting the address is probably only local**, what I want to achieve is to **set it outside the function** to be able work with this wariable. What do I wrong?

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var myPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
var address = "";

            //get address
            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': myPosition}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (results[1]) {
                        address = results[1].formatted_address;
                        alert('Inside: '+ address);
                    } else {
                        alert('No results found');

                    }
                } else {
                    alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                }
            });
alert ('Outside address: '+address);
```

**Edit**: 
It turned out that it's problem of assynchronous comunication. The outside alert is executed before the the geocoder.geocode is executed. So can I somehow stop executing the script till it will be executed? Synchronize it somehow, to be able work with this variable?

Comment: Welcome to the world of Asynchronous communication. What you want to do can not happen.

Comment: It's not a problem of variable *scope*, but of *timing*. Your "outside address" alert alerts first, doesn't it?

Comment: Well, actually yes. Can I synchronize it somehow?

Comment: @user1097772: No. Your only choice is to put the outside alert (and also the variable declaration) inside the callback

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the link to solution

Answer (score 0):

Well the first thing i'd check is my order of operations, it could be that the alert is executing BEFORE your geocoder is executing, try running your alert in a console view after the whole javascript runs.

If address is still staying undeclared do this on your line.

```
window.address = results[1].formatted_address;
```

this will set address as a window variable, which is the same scope as declaring var address outside of any function.

Comment: It's now problem of operation.

Comment: to fix that you can set a timeout.

    setTimeout(function(){alert ('Outside address: '+address);}, 1000);